# Failed to create a raster-brick from a netCDF file (.nc)

Tags: r, linux, netcdf

I am trying to build a raster-brick from a netCDF file (network Common Data Form)

leave this [link](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/whatsnetCDF.html) for more information () but to make a brick (which is part of the package raster) throws me the following error:

> Loading required namespace: ncdf4
>   Failed with error: ‘there is no package called ‘ncdf4’’
>   Error: requireNamespace("ncdf4") is not TRUE

after that try installing the package ncdf4 but throws the following error when trying to install:

> Error, nc-config not found or not executable. This is a script that comes with the
>   netcdf library, version 4.1-beta2 or later, and must be present for configuration
>   to succeed.
>   If you installed the netcdf library (and nc-config) in a standard location, nc-config
>   should be found automatically. Otherwise, you can specify the full path and name of
>   the nc-config script by passing the --with-nc-config=/full/path/nc-config argument
>   flag to the configure script. For example:
>   ./configure --with-nc-config=/sw/dist/netcdf4/bin/nc-config
>
> ### Special note for R users:
>
> To pass the configure flag to R, use something like this:
>   R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-nc-config=/home/joe/bin/nc-config" ncdf4
>   where you should replace /home/joe/bin etc. with the location where you have
>   installed the nc-config script that came with the netcdf 4 distribution.

How I can resolve this error?

I am new user in Linux, my Linux distro is Linux mint 17.1 and my version of R is 3.2.2

Comment: Have you installed `netcdf4` on your system?

Comment: Install the netcdf develepment *system* (not R) packages first - `sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You should install and the ncdf4 package.

```
install.packages("ncdf4")
```

Then be sure to run library(ncdf4) before running the brick function from raster. Below is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
r <- brick("E:\\test.nc",varname="precip")
r
```